# System.out.println() is not printing in JBoss EAP 6.2 Console

Tags: jboss-eap-6

I have a simple servlet with a spring service call Here the doGet method

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("==========================TEST=======================");
    logger.info("Inside doGet");

    WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext());
    MYServiceIF mYServiceIF= (MYServiceIF) wac.getBean("mYService", MYServiceImpl.class);       
    System.out.println("------------------------" + applicationContext);

    //*********************
    int recordsFetched = mYServiceIF.readInfo();
    //*********************
    logger.info("No ofrecords fetched" + recordsFetched );
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<HTML>");
    out.println("<HEAD>");
    out.println("<TITLE>Servlet Testing</TITLE>");
    out.println("</HEAD>");
    out.println("<BODY>");
    out.println("Welcome to the Servlet Testing Center: No of Records fetched in Service"               + recordsFetched);
    out.println("</BODY>");
    out.println("</HTML>");

}
```

The system.out.println is not printing anything, I am getting the output in a web page with data, 
What could be possibly wrong that the Sysout is not working but out.println is working. 
When I start the Local JBOSS EAP 6.2 Server the start up log is printed but after that nothing is printed in Sysout, but the programs is running. Please help.

Comment: Do you have a log4j configuration file in your deployment?

Comment: I found the problem, yes I have a log4j configuration prop file, and it was residing in two places by mistake. I removed one of them an its working. Lesson learned is 2 log4j.prop file will stop your Sysout also.